# Auto reference for vectors?

Tags: c++, reference, stl, iterator, range-based-loop

The following code will not alter the contents of `i` in the for loop:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> combinationSum(vector<int>& candidates, int target) {
        if (target == 0) {return vector<vector<int>>{{}};} 
        else if (!candidates.size() || target < 0) {return vector<vector<int>>();}
        else {
            vector<vector<int>> with = combinationSum(candidates, target - candidates[0]); 
            vector<int> new_vector(candidates.begin() + 1, candidates.end());
            vector<vector<int>> without = combinationSum(new_vector, target);
            for (auto i : with) {i.push_back(candidates[0]);}

            with.insert(with.end(), without.begin(), without.end());
            return with;
                                        
        }
    }
};
```

However, if I change it to `auto& i : with ...`, it works. Is there a reason why? I thought references were only relevant if you are working with pointed objects or if you don't want the variable (in this case `i`) to change in the local scope.

Comment: What do you mean by pointed objects?

Comment: If you do `auto& i` and then `i.push_back(...)` you alter `with`. Otherwise you alter a copy of  the inner `vector`

Answer (score 5):

`auto` defaults to being neither `const` nor a reference. So `for (auto i : with) {` is storing to `i` by value, which invokes the copy constructor for each of the nested `vector`s. That copy has nothing to do with the version stored in your `vector` of `vector`s, so no changes persist when the copy goes away. Your addition of `&` makes it a reference that aliases the underlying inner `vector` so changes to the reference change the original `vector`.

If you *don't* want to change the object in question, the efficient way to do this is to use `const auto&` to both prevent changes and avoid copies; it's fairly rare you want to iterate by value this way unless you really want a mutable copy that won't affect the original, since the copy constructor costs can get pretty nasty.

Comment: What does `auto` default to? Would the same error still persist if I used `vector<int> i` instead?

Comment: @bayesianpower: You'd get the same error; `auto` is type-deducing to `vector<int>` already, but you remain responsible for `const` or reference-qualifying it if you want that.

Comment: Is this generally true any time I utilize equality in C++? So for example:

1. If I had a function `int A(vector<int> B) {...`, would `B` be a copy of the vector I pass in?
2. Any time I iterated through any container: the iterated variable is always a copy?

So then would the only way to modify the underlying data without pointers is to use references in every case?

Comment: @bayesianpower you really should start with a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) . All of your questions are about basic C++ concepts like values and references and you should really learn them from a good source instead of you throwing darts in the dark hoping something sticks and then trying to figure out basic concepts as you go.

Answer (score 2):

On using `for (auto i : with)`, you are copying the element `i` from the vector `with` and then using it.

On using `for (auto & i : with)`, you are referencing the element `i` from the vector `with` and then using it.

Your vector would change if you were copying the addresses of its elements then dereferencing (or you were using a vector of pointers) but here you are copying the objects.

Answer (score 0):

`for (auto i : with) { ...` is equivalent to:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it = with.begin(); it != i.end(); it++)
{
    vector<int> i = *it;
    ...
```

And you can then see that `i` makes a copy each time round the loop.  Changes to this copy therefore affect only the copy, which is a temporary.

OTOH `for (auto &i : with)` ... is equivalent to:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it = with.begin(); it != i.end(); it++)
{
    vector<int>& i = *it;
    ...
```

which assigns a reference each time round the loop.  Changes to this reference therefore affect the original object.